# Make parent menu clickable

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to make the top level menu items clickable while still having the dropdowns show up?

[see website](http://www.dawaf.co.uk/creative-mapping/)

I am using bootstrap 3 on my Wordpress site using these instructions: http://www.creativewebdesign.ro/en/blog/wordpress/create-a-responsive-wordpress-theme-with-bootstrap-3-header-and-footer/

**header.php**

```
        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse menu_left',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav menu_left_middle',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
        ?>

        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'submenu',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse menu_right',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav menu_right_middle',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
        ?>

</nav>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate the same by a screenshot?

Comment: no, its not possible. But some idea, If you are using ajax request, and javascript cookie may you can.

Comment: I can't add images but I have provided a link to the website. The menu on the right hand side (Art / Architecture) etc

Comment: I don't understand the question. The top level menu is allready clickable, its an `a` element..

Comment: If you hover over 'Art' a dropdown appears but the parent link (Art) isn't clickable. I would like it to be clickable.

Comment: do you have an access to operate with top level menu items? if yes, just try to put a "href" there

Comment: I have added header.php

Comment: hey pal did you find the solution coz i have the same problem now

Answer (score 20):

For me it worked this way:
I assume you make usage of the [wp-bootstrap-navwalker](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)

Open up the wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php with your editor and look up for line approx. 83

```
// If item has_children add atts to a.
if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
   $atts['href']        = '#';
   $atts['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
   $atts['class']           = 'dropdown-toggle';
} else {
   $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
}
```

Change this piece of code to:

```
// If item has_children add atts to a.
if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
   $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
   //$atts['data-toggle']   = 'dropdown';
   $atts['class']           = 'dropdown-toggle';
} else {
   $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
}
```

Note: $att['href'] is enabled now, the the $atts['data-toggle'] is disabled which makes the parent link clickable.

Now open up your style.css and add this piece of code to activate the hover function for your WordPress menu with dropdown and clickable parent.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Note:
The behaviour of the menu will change slightly on small devices with small screens.
No additional jQuery required.

Comment: Is it possible to accept my own answer?
If so, please let me know how!

Comment: Thanks a lot. helped a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is awesome

Comment: This is great, it works on iphone but not on android? dropdown menu appears but the clickable item link will instantly start to load

Answer (score 1):

You can just add class 'disabled' into that element using jQuery.
See example below:

```
<script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {

           jQuery('ul li > a.dropdown-toggle').addClass('disabled');
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure – for each of the top-level anchors, make sure to define your href and remove the data-toggle attribute. For example, instead of:

```
<a title="Design" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Design <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Use:

```
<a title="Design" href="/design" class="dropdown-toggle">Design <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

(or whatever you want the href to be).

Comment: I have added the header.php code for nav. I can't see the above to edit it.

Comment: The php isn't doing that. Open dev tools and inspect the element you want to be clickable. It has an anchor tag around it with a href value of "#". The "default action" of the anchor tag is being prevented however b/c it has a data-toggle="dropdown" attribute applied to it. You would have to remove that data-attribute. If you can't do it directly in the code, and you can't modify it via your php (doesn't appear to be the case), then as a final resort you could use JS/jQuery to target $('a.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="dropdown"]')