# Bootstrap menu dropdown problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my problem is with a bootstrap menu. I'm using `wp_bootstrap_navwalker` in my WP theme, and I found some solutions on the web to enable more deeper `nav`, but I can't find the solution to make it work fine on desktop *and* on smaller devices.

I have this structure of the menu:

[image: Menu Structure]

My question is: How to enable all menu items, dropdown items and sub dropdown items to be clickable on all devices (on hover on desktop and on click on small devices). I suppose that on small devices there should be some function that lets you to click 2 time to access the link and on 1 click just to enable opening of the sub items.

I currently have [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748558/make-parent-menu-clickable), but doesnt quite do what I want, as my sub dropdown items show up at the same time like this:

[image: example]

[This is the exact code (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/pevoje/j34j24nr) that I use in `header.php` and my `style.scss`.

Any ideas?

Comment: it would be usefull if you added your own code, and we can help you out based on that; either pour it here, or use a jsfiddle/pastebin/whatever comes in mid

Comment: Tnx for the remark, here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pevoje/j34j24nr/

Comment: Thanks for the JS.Fiddle unfortunately it wont parse PHP for you so you will need to add the HTML code manually. Right now it shows broken and we cant see the menu functionality.

Comment: cant really paste html as I use php for the result of output of the menu

Comment: Right click browser and click 'View page source'.