# Code to use jquery to make parent menu item to be clickable

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

On the page: [Make parent menu clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748558/make-parent-menu-clickable/29291975#29291975), the jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('ul li > a.dropdown-toggle').addClass('disabled');
});
```

...was given as an alternate solution. What I'd like to know is, can one then just add "....addClass('enabled');" instead, to make the parent menu item clickable?

I don't want to put a custom link in the menu, I don't want to modify bootstrap files, I don't want to modify any other files except the external jquery (".js") file in my own WordPress Theme, as well as my theme files (header.php, page.php, etc.) of course.

I have tried to add the dropdown-toggle class to the wp_nav_menu like this:

`menu_class' => 'list_no_decoration dropdown-toggle',`

and then simply modified the above code to:

`jQuery('ul li > a.dropdown-toggle').addClass('enabled');`

But sadly, the parent menu item is still not clickable. I really like this solution as it is very simple and can easily be repeated in other themes i end up designing.

My current code looks as follows:

**header.php**

```
<div class="container-fluid"  id="header_nav">
  <div class="row" id="main_nav_row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="header_nav_col">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
        <?php
            wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
                    'menu' => 'Categories', 
                    'container_class' => 'main-menu', 
                    'container_id' => 'header', 
                    'theme_location' => 'header',
                    'menu_class' => 'list_no_decoration',
                    'menu_id' => 'top_nav',
                )
            );
        ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
ul.list_no_decoration { /* "list_no_decoration" as per menu_class in wp_nav_menu */
    list-style: none;
    border:0;  /* Reset */
    margin:0; /* Reset */
    padding:0; /* Reset */
    outline:0; /* Reset */
}
ul.list_no_decoration#top_nav {
    vertical-align: top;
    top:0;
    width:99.9%;
    padding-left: 0.05%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.list_no_decoration#top_nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
}
ul.list_no_decoration#top_nav li a {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.list_no_decoration#top_nav li > a:link {
}
ul.list_no_decoration#top_nav a:visited {
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
ul.list_no_decoration#top_nav a:active {
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
ul.list_no_decoration#top_nav > li > a:hover {
}

/* sub-level menu item */
ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    border:0;  /* Reset */
    margin:0; /* Reset */
    padding:0; /* Reset */
    outline:0; /* Reset */
}
ul.sub-menu li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    border:0;  /* Reset */
    margin:0; /* Reset */
    padding:0; /* Reset */
    outline:0; /* Reset */
    top: 30px;
    left: -11px;
    background-color:black;
}
ul.list_no_decoration#top_nav  > li ul {
    vertical-align: top;
    top: 0;
    border:0;  /* Reset */
    margin:0; /* Reset */
    padding:0; /* Reset */
    outline:0; /* Reset */
    display: none; /* display: none; to make it invisible until hover */
}
ul.list_no_decoration#top_nav > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Here's what the menu currently looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdvsY.png)

Comment: Is there a link to your code/website that we can have a look at?

Comment: Apologies, I've edited the code in the question. (still getting used to posting properly on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Okay, can you post your HTML markup and the CSS/JS code you are trying?

Comment: It's all part of a WordPress theme btw. I will clean up the rest of the CSS when I'm done, just trying to get the functionality for now. (don't judge)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the HTML menu and tell what items do you want to enable

Comment: shariqkhan I've added it now. Marketing is the parent link I'm trying to make clickable. I'm starting to think I should just use a JQuery click event. I've already added a hover event for the mouse cursor to act as a link.

Comment: It is very difficult to guage what problem you are facing from screenshot alone, though it helps a bit.
Can you prepare a JSFiddle or a bootsnipp with the HTML code that is getting generated from the wp_nav_menu function call?

Comment: Thank you for the effort and apologies for the late reply @shariqkhan, I'm not sure where or how, but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

just make your HTML like this dont put `<a href=" ">` in your dropdown only the parent menu

```
<nav>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="YOUR_LINK_HERE">MENU</a>
        <ul>
            <li>display 1</li>
            <li>display 2</li>
            <li>display 3</li>
            <li>display 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I've solved the problem somehow, and this is in WordPress btw, so the entire navigation section is generated dynamically.

I wanted all links clickable, what you are describing is making some "unclickable"...not sure what I did, but its fixed now. Thank you for the effort @pure-rhymer-organization