# How can I make the parent item of a drop-down clickable with a toggle button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wp-nav-walker

First of all, if you think something is wrong with my question, please explain to me what you want me to change to make it better. I've worked on this for days with very little success, and I'm really trying my best, but I'm also new to this topic, so please be patient with me.

I'm working on a child theme of WooCommerce Storefront with Bootstrap 4.0.

I'm trying to use the [jQuery Smartmenus plugin]
(https://www.smartmenus.org/about/introduction-to-smartmenus-jquery/) with their Bootstrap 4 addon for the small-screen version of my main menu because it comes with the toggle button I want. Here's how I want it to work: Just like their ["SmartMenus Bootstrap 4 Addon (Navbar)" Demo]
(http://vadikom.github.io/smartmenus/src/demo/bootstrap-4-navbar.html), with one difference: I want the parent item to be clickable, so that it leads to the link rather than toggling the drop-down. The +/- button should be the only drop-down.

I managed to get the parent link to be clickable using a part of the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748558/make-parent-menu-clickable). I'm using the same [nav walker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker), just the Bootstrap 4 version. In that file, I replaced the original line 206 with "$atts['href']          = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';" as suggested in the linked question. I did not change the CSS though, and I don't want anything particular to happen on hover.

My problem now is that both a click on the parent link and a click on the +/- result in the drop-down being expanded for a moment before the parent link is loaded and I'm directed to that link. I would like the parent link to not do any toggling, but more importantly, I need the +/- button to toggle the drop-down instead of functioning as a link to the parent item's page. How can I get it to toggle the drop-down?

I tried to remove the data-toggle attribute and the drop-down toggle class in the same part of the walker file, but that did not make any difference.

Here is the code for my small screen menu in the header.php:

```
<div id="small-screen-menu" class="d-block d-sm-none">
   <?php sk_smartmenus_init_in_footer(); ?>
   <nav id="xs-site-navigation" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm" role="navigation">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-site-navigation" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <?php
         wp_nav_menu( array(
           'theme_location'    => 'main_menu',
           'depth'             => 4,
           'container'         => 'div',
           'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-1-collapse',
           'container_id'      => 'main-site-navigation',
           'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav sm sm-simple',
           'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
           'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
         ) );
      ?>                            
   </nav>
</div>
```

Here are the corresponding functions in functions.php:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'sk_smartmenus_init_in_footer' ) ) {
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sk_smartmenus_init_in_footer');
   function sk_smartmenus_init_in_footer() {
    add_action( 'print_footer_scripts', 'smartmenus_init' );
   }
}
function smartmenus_init() { 
   ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
            $('#menu-categories-menu').smartmenus();
          });
       </script>
   <?php 
}
```

I'm really not sure if those functions are correct. Do I need to change more content of the walker file? Or the Smartmenus JS? If so, what? I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

PS: If you have a solution without the Smartmenus plugin that creates a clickable menu item with a toggle button, I'll take it! I'm not really attached to Smartmenus.

Update December 2018: I still haven't figured this out. Can anyone help me? Please?

Comment: @PPL thanks for the edits. The class I meant is actually called "dropdown-toggle" though. I went with Bootstrap's spelling.

Comment: Suggest you include a link to a site that implements what you are looking to do OR otherwise explain in more detail what you want to do. This will make it easier for folks to propose a solution.